# How to append dataurl from canvas image to backgroung image of the table

Tags: html, html5-canvas

i am not able to append dataurl from canvas image to backgroung image of the table

this is my canvas function

```
var container=document.getElementById("pageContainer")
var origCanvas=document.getElementById("page1");
origCanvas.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;border:1px solid black");
var wmContext = origCanvas.getContext('2d');
wmContext.globalAlpha=0.5;
// setup text for filling
wmContext.font = "72px Comic Sans MS" ;
wmContext.fillStyle = "red";
// get the metrics with font settings
var metrics = wmContext.measureText("@ViewBag.entityTitle");
var width = metrics.width;
// height is font size
var height = 72;

// change the origin coordinate to the middle of the context
wmContext.translate(origCanvas.width/2, origCanvas.height/2);
// rotate the context (so it's rotated around its center)
wmContext.rotate(-Math.atan(origCanvas.height/origCanvas.width));
// as the origin is now at the center, just need to center the text
wmContext.fillText("@ViewBag.entityTitle", -width / 2, height / 2);

    //DataUrl = origCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var dataURL = origCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('my').src = dataURL;
    var data = atob(DataUrl.substring("data:image/png;base64,".length)),
     asArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
        asArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([asArray.buffer], { type: "image/png" });

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);

    $('#my').appendChild(img);
```

**Here i am getting image of the canvas**

```
 <img id="my"/>
```

Now i want this image as background of my Table or a div as how to do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use canvas as the background to a div you can do this:

```
// get a reference to the div you want to apply the background to

var myDiv=document.getElementById("anyDiv");

// create a url string from your origCanvas

var url="url("+origCanvas.toDataURL()+")";

// apply the url as the background of your div

myDiv.style.backgroundImage=url;
```

BTW, you can use your origCanvas.toDataURL as img.src (no need for all the conversions you have in your code):

```
img.src=origCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: this is not working for me donot knw what mistake i am doing?

Comment: I've edited my answer.  BTW, you can set an image element's source to a canvas much more simply than your code: img.src=canvas.toDataURL().